# Writing in column near a grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm making a grid using tikz, and I need to write some variables on the side in the middle of the lines.
This is the result I would like to get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label=corner]{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt]

\begin{document}

    \begin{textblock*}{200pt}(150pt,150pt)
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
            \draw[step=1cm,black, thick] (0.1, 0.1) grid (8.9,6.9);
            \fill[red] (1,6) circle (0.2cm);
            \def\ynode{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
            \def\names{F , E , D , C , B , A}
            \begin{scope}<+->;
                %\foreach \y/\ytext in { 6/A, 5/B, 4/C, 3/D, 2/E, 1/F}
                %\foreach \n/\ytext in {\ynode/\names}{
                    %\draw[black, midway, xshift=-12pt, yshift=\y cm]  node[below] {$\ytext$};
                    %[xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
                    %(0,0) -- (0,2) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] 
                    %{\footnotesize F};%}
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{textblock*}
    
\end{document}
```

I did some tries and I got the number part right but I can't understand how to write the letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're labeling every horizontal and vertical line, you don't really gain anything by using `grid`. Two `\foreach` loops draws and labels each line.

Note the use of `\tikzset`, which should be used instead of the out-of-date `\tikzstyle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{branch/.style={fill, circle, minimum size=5pt, inner sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\foreach \y[count=\n] in {F,...,A} \draw[thick] (.1,\n)node[left]{\y}--(7.9,\n);
\foreach \x[count=\n] in {0,2,5,6,9,11,12} \draw[thick] (\n,.1)node[below]{\x}--(\n,6.9);
\foreach \x/\y in {1/6,2/6,2/5,4/5,3/4,5/4,4/3,6/3,5/2,7/2,6/1,7/1} \node[branch] at (\x,\y){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```